# Go Float32bit() result not expected

Tags: go

eg: 16777219.0 dec to bit

```
16777219 -> 1 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0011

Mantissa: 23 bit
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 001

Exponent:
24+127 = 151
151 -> 10010111

Result shoud be:
0_10010111_000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001

1001011100000000000000000000001
```

but:

```golang
fmt.Printf("%b\n", math.Float32bits(float32(16777219.0)))

// 1001011100000000000000000000010
```

why the Go Float32bit() result not expected?

reference:

- [base-conversion.ro](https://binary-system.base-conversion.ro/convert-real-numbers-from-decimal-system-to-32bit-single-precision-IEEE754-binary-floating-point.php)

---

update:

```golang
fmt.Printf("16777216.0:%b\n", math.Float32bits(float32(16777216.0)))
fmt.Printf("16777217.0:%b\n", math.Float32bits(float32(16777217.0)))
//16777216.0:1001011100000000000000000000000
//16777217.0:1001011100000000000000000000000
fmt.Printf("16777218.0:%b\n", math.Float32bits(float32(16777218.0)))
//16777218.0:1001011100000000000000000000001
fmt.Printf("16777219.0:%b\n", math.Float32bits(float32(16777219.0)))
fmt.Printf("16777220.0:%b\n", math.Float32bits(float32(16777220.0)))
fmt.Printf("16777221.0:%b\n", math.Float32bits(float32(16777221.0)))
//16777219.0:1001011100000000000000000000010
//16777220.0:1001011100000000000000000000010
//16777221.0:1001011100000000000000000000010

fmt.Printf("000:%f\n", math.Float32frombits(0b_10010111_00000000000000000000000))
// 000:16777216.000000
fmt.Printf("001:%f\n", math.Float32frombits(0b_10010111_00000000000000000000001))
// 001:16777218.000000
fmt.Printf("010:%f\n", math.Float32frombits(0b_10010111_00000000000000000000010))
// 010:16777220.000000
fmt.Printf("011:%f\n", math.Float32frombits(0b_10010111_00000000000000000000011))
// 011:16777222.000000
```

what is the rules?

Comment: Go gives the correct IEEE 754 binary floating point result - round to nearest, ties to even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go gives the correct IEEE-754 binary floating point result - round to nearest, ties to even.

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://go.dev/ref/spec)
>
> ```
> float32     the set of all IEEE-754 32-bit floating-point numbers
> ```

Decimal

```
16777219
```

is binary

```
1000000000000000000000011
```

For 32-bit IEEE-754 floating-point binary binary, the 24-bit integer mantissa is

```
100000000000000000000001.1
```

Round to nearest, ties to even gives

```
100000000000000000000010
```

Removing the implicit one bit for the 23-bit mantissa gives

```
00000000000000000000010
```

---

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    const n = 16777219
    fmt.Printf("%d\n", n)
    fmt.Printf("%b\n", n)
    f := float32(n)
    fmt.Printf("%g\n", f)
    fmt.Printf("%b\n", math.Float32bits(f))
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/yMaVkuiSJ5A

```
16777219
1000000000000000000000011
1.677722e+07
1001011100000000000000000000010
```

Answer (score 1):

Why the result is not expected: **You're expecting the wrong result.**

The IEEE 754 standard specifies that, [per Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Roundings_to_nearest):

> if the number falls midway, it is rounded to the nearest value with an even least significant digit.

So when rounding 16777219, which is midway between 16777218 and 16777218. The "round up" option 16777220 gives an even LSB, and is the correct result you're observing.

Comment: 16777217.0 is between 16777216 and 16777218, The "round up" option 16777218, but bit is same 16777216, why? thx

Comment: @Yifan 16777218 has 1 in its last bit of mantissa, so it is not favored over 16777216 or 16777220.